# Automapper IValueResolver does not support Nullable type Guid

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-5

Recently I updated automapper 5+ version and realized that IValueresolver does not work as expected for Nullable type Guid.

I have created a value resolver as follows:

```
public class GanttTaskParentIdResolver : IValueResolver<GanttTask, Task, Guid?>
{
    private IUow Uow;
    public GanttTaskParentIdResolver(IUow _uow)
    {
        Uow = _uow;
    }
    public Guid? Resolve(GanttTask source, Task destination, Guid? member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.parentIdRaw != null && source.parentIdRaw != 0)
        {
            var task = Uow.Tasks.GetAll().Where(con => con.Id == source.parentIdRaw).FirstOrDefault();
            return task.GUID;
        }
        else return null;
    }

}
```

and Mapping configuration as follows:

```
cfg.CreateMap<GanttTask, Task>()
              .IgnoreAllNonExisting()
              .ForMember(dst => dst.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Children))
              .ForMember(dst => dst.ParentId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<GanttTaskParentIdResolver>())
              .ForMember(dst => dst.CalendarId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<GanttTaskCalendarIdResolver>());
```

The dst.ParentId is Nullable Guid.
It does not trigger GanttTaskParentIdResolver for resolving and always gives null for ParentId.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Update - i tested for nullable int and it works. it seems a issue with nullable Guid

Comment: Could you reduce the code to a minimal case that reproduces the issue. There is too much code here that references types we do not know about, either include the types, or preferably remove the need for them.

Comment: @Jayakaran Did you tried `Nullable<Guid>` instead of `Guid?`

Comment: @Rabban Yub but not works

Comment: I am also facing this issue...Is there any solution for this?